# How to iterate over enums?

Tags: d

How to iterate over enums ?

It is donot work

```
enum Bool : int { no = 0, yes }
Bool boll;
foraech( e, bool){
    writeln(e);
}
```

Comment: I don't know "d", but is that a typo on your second line, should `boll` be `bool`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are so many mistakes within your code, so I just give you a code that works:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.traits;

void main() {
    enum Bool { no = 0, yes }
    foreach (e; [EnumMembers!Bool]) {
        writeln(e);
    }
}
```